# How can one show the sum of observed variables is "zero"?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance

Let's assume one is collecting measurements $x_i(t)$ of "true" variables $\bar x_i(t)$, where $0\le i<n$ is the index identifying each variable and $t$ represents different sampling times.

Let's also assume true variables are linked together (via a dynamical relationship for example) such that : $\sum_i \bar x_i(t) = 0$.

Differences between $x_i(t)$ and $\bar x_i(t)$ are noises that we can label $\epsilon_i(t) = x_i(t) - \bar x_i(t)$.

Note that at any instant $t$, the sum of measured variables $x_i(t)$ will be different than 0: $S=\sum_i x_i(t)=\sum_i \epsilon_i(t) \neq 0$.

Note that noise and true variables can be assumed to have zero mean: $\langle \bar x_i(t) \rangle=0$, $\langle \epsilon_i(t) \rangle=0$, where $\langle \cdot \rangle$ is the mean operator and taken over time/samples.

We could for example be measuring the acceleration ($ma=\bar x_0$) and force ($F=-\bar x_1$) exerted on an object. Newton's second law of motion would then tell us that: $ma-F=0$ or equivalently $\bar x_0+\bar x_1=0$.

I'd like to show:

1. that the balance does indeed "hold", i.e. that the sum is "small" with statistical significance. Given the assumption of zero mean, we are interested in quantifying $S$ variations amplitude and showing it is small.
2. that each variable measured does indeed contribute to the balance and quantify to what "extent" it does so.

I'm struggling to formulate a good statistical setup to do this, hence this post.

The ideas that I have for now are the following:

For 1:  compare the variance of the sum $S$ with the sum of individual variances: $\langle S^2 \rangle$ vs $\sum_i \langle x_i^2 \rangle$, where $\langle \cdot \rangle$ is taken over time/samples. The rationale is that if each variable was uncorrolated with others the variance of $S$ would be the sum of individual variances.

For 2: compare the variance of the sum $S_j=\sum_{i\neq j}x_i$ with that of $S$. If the variable $x_j$ does not contribute to the balance, the variance of $S_j$ should be larger than that of $S$.

Any ideas about this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Do you mean you want to set up a random variable that reverts to its mean over time? Or instead, you want to proof that something that has mean of zero will revert to zero? The first one is simple, just make it X(t+1)-X(t) be a N(-X(t),1) random variable. For second, it is impossible as it is false,e.g. Martingales.

Comment: I do not follow the double index with $i$ and $t$. What do each of those mean, and how do they differ in meaning? // Do you mean that you want to show the expected value of the sum to be zero or to show that the sum itself is zero? From comment #1, I concede that I do not 100% follow what you're doing, but I would think that, unless every $x_i(t)$ has $P(x_i(t) = 0) = 1$, there is some positive probability that the sum would not be zero.

Comment: @Dave Sorry, I was thinking on average on the sequence and I did not write it out.

Comment: So you want to test something about $\mathbb E[x_i(t)]=0$, but what do $i$ and $t$ mean, and how do they differ in meaning?

Comment: thanks for your feedback !
Clearly my description of the problem was too fusy.
I tried to improve it. Please let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A good setup for this problem is as an [errors-in-variables model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models).

We have observations, $x_i$, of underlying variables, $\bar x_i$, with noise $\epsilon_i$:
$$
x_i = \bar x_i + \epsilon_i.
$$
We are looking for coefficients $a_i$ and $b$ such that
$$
\bar x_0 = \sum_{i=1}^N a_i \bar x_i + b.
$$
This looks a lot like a linear regression problem! The only difference is that there is noise in all of the $x_i $ variables, which needs to be taken into account.

For your two questions:

1. Note that the balance won't necessarily hold for any individual sample. Even if we know the correct coefficients,
   $$
   \sum_{i=1}^N a_i x_i + b - x_0 = \sum_{i=1}^N a_i \epsilon_i - \epsilon_0
   $$
   This can have large variance for large $N$ or large $a_i$ values. However, if we take $K$ such samples, then averaging over $K$,
   $$
    \frac{1}{K} \sum_{k=1}^K \left( \sum_{i=1}^N a_i \epsilon_i^k - \epsilon_0^k \right)
   $$
   The variance will scale as $1 / K$.

2. We can use an errors-in-variables model to infer the values of the coefficients.

   - the values of $a_i$ will tell us how much each $x_i$ contributes relative to $x_0$. (A note of caution here is that, while the choice of $x_0$ was arbitrary, it is important that it contributes to the sum significantly enough.)
   - a confidence interval or a posterior distribution over $b$ gives how likely $b = 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback Luke.
I'll have to dig into this thread of literature.
Introducing $a_i$ parameters may make sense for some variables but not necessarily for other and I'll search for ways to fix these (if this makes any sense).

Comment: That makes sense. One thought: maybe you could put all of the variables that don't have a coefficient on the left side of the equation, so you're regressing against their sum.